# How does Android Substrate work?

Tags: java, android, hook, code-injection, cydia-substrate

In Android world, there are two popular injection/hijack/hooking frameworks :

**Xposed** and **Android Substrate**

The Xposed's mechanism is described in [a development tutorial](https://github.com/rovo89/XposedBridge/wiki/Development-tutorial).

The author of **Android Substrate** compared the two frameworks [in FAQ](http://www.cydiasubstrate.com/id/34058d37-3198-414f-a696-73e97e0a80db/) and [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2466101), but he didn't say how it works.

I just wonder:

**How does Android Substrate work?**

Answer (score 3):

Jay Freeman(Saurik) in this post(http://www.cydiasubstrate.com/id/34058d37-3198-414f-a696-73e97e0a80db/) talks about the deference in xposed and substrate and also talks about how they deffer in the way they work its a great read.

Answer (score 1):

Although the similarities are vast between the two frameworks, the actual implementation of hooking processes etc differs enough for you to be able to have both frameworks running side by side.

However, the biggest benefits that I can see for Substrate over XPosed, is the fact that XPosed removes the Java Security Model, while Substrate preserves it, as well as having the ability to wait for a class to be loaded before hooking a method as described in the following quote from @xmllmx answer regarding "[Orthogonality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonality_%28programming%29)";

> To make this easier, Xposed provides a set of helpers for common use cases: you can hook when the VM starts, when Zygote takes control, when a particular package is loaded, or when a command line application is executed. You need to know which of these to use, and it is still unclear how you'd hook a class loaded via a dyamic runtime-created class loader (such as against downloaded code).
>
> Substrate instead does away with all of this, thanks to MS.hookClassLoad, an API it provides that allows you to wait for particular classes to be loaded from any class loader at any time. This allows you to write hooks in a way that is less brittle to changes, less prone to simple mistakes, and less limited by how the developer of the target application decided to load their program's code.

In conclusion, in my opinion anyway, both frameworks a very similar and both viable options in achieving the same goal. The only major weighing fact which separates them is the timescales between when each was released. Where XPosed has been around for much longer and has been tried and tested and put through it's paces over the interim between the  release of XPosed an the release of Cydia Substrate for Android, which Jay Freeman (Saurik) [openly acknowledges](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2466101)

Regardless of this, Cydia Substrate is a powerful and extremely viable alternative to XPosed. Furthermore, you don't have to only limit yourself to developing for one of these frameworks, because (as mentioned previously) both frameworks can be installed on your device without conflict, so developing for both or simply trying it, will in no way hinder you from using your currently install XPosed Modules, Packages or Extensions.